# Can not print in access but can print from word

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

I have office prof 2003.

Ms Word prints fine as does excel - I can output msAccess reports into word and print them, BUT when I try to print the MS Access reports it outputs blank pages (of the right number). These reports have worked before and do from another PC using same printer.

I have tried control panel to repair Office 2003 - no better result. I have also done a reinstallation from control panel - no change in my outputs.

What is going on?

Comment: Does this only happen with this one specific printer? Have you tried to print to a different printer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you look at all the printer setup controls for any clues, the properties and the setup.  This probably won't be it, but do look at them.

Also, can you get it to display a print preview on the screen of a simple table?

And try installing a virtual printer, like a pdf printer like PrimoPDF and see if you can print to that.  If so then reinstall your printer and/or Access.

Failing that, don't just fiddle with the setup.  **Rather uninstall and reinstall the whole darn thing.**  (It won't wipe out your data.)  I know this is a pain, but have had to do it to fix this sort of problem.

Also I've learned that objects can get messed up in Access 2003.  Make frequent back ups (with the Files | Backup up database..).  If a form or report goes bad in the process of editing it, just delete it, open your most recent backup side by side with your current project, drag the form or report from the one window to the other to copy the form or report from your backup to your project.